# Syntax for queryFilter.WhereClause in C#

Tags: arcobjects, c#, string, where-clause

I need help with a `queryFilter` WHERE clause that is giving me a headache.

All it does is to convert the search to uppercase and perform the search whether the result is uppercase or not (e.g. it will find "Jones" or JONES").

I have the following code in my VBA app:

```
Dim pQF as IQueryFilter
Set pQF = new QueryFilter
pQF.WhereClause = "upper(" & strFieldToSearch &") LIKE '%" & UCase(Replace(strSearch,"'","''")) & "%'"
```

In my C# code I have tried various ways including:

```
queryFilter.WhereClause =  searchField + " LIKE '%" + search.Replace("'","''") + "%'";

queryFilter.WhereClause = strSearchField.ToUpper() + " LIKE " + "'%" + strSearch.ToUpper() + "%'";
```

But it can't find the record. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried the following

```
queryFilter.WhereClause = "upper(" + strSearchField + ") LIKE'%" + strSearch.ToUpper() + "%'";
```

and got it working.